# Expected value of multivariate normal with single integration

Tags: numerical-methods, normal-distribution, expected-value, correlation

My goal is to find the expected value of a sum of correlated standard normal random variables. Suppose that $f$ is some function and $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ are polynomials of degree $m$. Furthermore, $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ are all standard normal with correlation coefficient $\rho$.

I want to find an efficient way to evaluate
\begin{equation}\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\sum p_i(X_i)\right)\right]\end{equation}

Obviously, this could be done by integrating over all $X_i$. But this is numerically to expensive. I was hoping to find a way to only use a single integral, given that the random variables are all equally distributed.

It would also be sufficient to find the characteristic function of $\sum p_i(X_i)$, which looks like it should be possible, but I failed so far.

Comment: I doubt the solution exists. Perhaps you could have a asymptotic solution if you suppose that $n$ is large and the polynomials are all equal.

Answer (score 1):

"$f$ is some function" makes the problem impossible. With $f$ being anything (including integrable, I suppose), the resulting random variable $Z=f\left(\sum p_i(X_i)\right)$ can have any distribution, and you are asking for a method to calculate any expectation effectively (whatever this means).

That said, (and amazingly) Monte-Carlo will work!

Comment: Optimally, I would know be able to derive the distribution of $\sum p_i(X_i)$, in which case, the specifics of $f$ does not matter. To give a bit of context, $f$ would be something like $\max(x,0)$.

I am specifically trying to avoid monte carlo to obtain at least a semi-analytic expression

Comment: I think you need to make up your mind first, what $f$ may look like! The specifics of $f$ will always matter, for any underlying distribution of inputs. The more restricted $f$, the more likely that your problem can be solved.

Comment: And you definitely should edit your question accordingly. Everything else is just confusing to people.